# Port forward to different local IP addresses

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, bittorrent

For the purpose of P2P file sharing ( Bittorrent, Acestream ) I want to open a port on my router and forward it to my laptop's IP address. This is all OK and working but the problem is that sometimes I am connected through cable and the other time through WIFI. What should be the most graceful way to make this work. I have considered the following option - assign the same local IP to 2 different MAC addresses in the DHCP configuration of the router. This did not work well with my particular router, maybe because the switch between Ethernet/WiFi happens fast and the IP is not released properly.

So my question is what other options are there and is there something more graceful to solve this problem.

Comment: Same IP for different MACs - bad idea. If you have Windows - I would create 2 scripts. 1st disables WiFi network connection, enables LAN network connection and sets the static IP you wish to have. 2nd would disable LAN network connection, enable WiFi network connection and (again) set the static IP to the one you want. A good idea would be to change the IP settings to DHCP before disabling it so Windows would not complain that the IP is used on another adapter. You should be able to perform this with the `netsh` command - [see here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am using Linux but still can take away the idea of using static IP addresses.